# Regex reverse search using Lucene

Tags: java, regex, lucene

Assume that my stored Lucene documents have a `regex` stored field that represents a regular expression.

i.e. `doc.add(new StringField("regex", "\d{3}[A-G]\d{2}[A-G]\d{2}", Store.YES));`

My search input is something like `123D56G89`.

Is there a way to do a reverse matching in my TermQuery and fetch all documents that match the given input?

Coming from RDBMS background, MariaDB has `REGEXP` function for this.

Comment: Do you mean to match any string but the one that matches the pattern above? Like `"^(?!\d{3}[A-G]\d{2}[A-G]\d{2}$).*"`?

Comment: I mean: Get input `123D56G89`, evaluate it with all documents that their saved regex matches that input and return those documents (if any).

Comment: Is this even possible out of the box, or will I have to write my own custom query class?

Comment: The only query type out-of-the-box - [RegexpQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/RegexpQuery.html) - works the other way round: the query is given a regexp, which is used to test plain strings in the indexed data. Furthermore, the Lucene flavor of regexp is [not full-featured](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html).

Comment: thought so. Might be an overkill to implement what I want :(

Comment: Well, Lucene regex does support matching any string but a specific one, `@&~([0-9]{3}[A-G][0-9]{2}[A-G][0-9]{2})`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to leverage search index features to search many documents in sublinear time, then **No**, with the information given in your question, there is not a way. You must examine every document in the index and act on each document's stored expression.

A regular expression is essentially a type of program. *In general,* without being able to reason about specific concepts encoded in the expression, evaluating it requires knowing the full expression, and the engine must actually run it. This means there's no way to *generally* summarize or categorize the field into a search index to speed up lookup. If you wish to check a string against N regular expressions, you must go through those N regular expressions one by one and check them. At that point, a search index is not providing any benefits to store, fetch, or manage them.

If you are totally fine with "slow" search, and you are dead-set on storing arbitrary expressions in this way, then technically **Yes**, you can implement a new type of query that treats a field as a regular expression and runs it against the input. I would not consider this a normal use of a search index, but the logic is as possible technically as any other sort of evaluation.

**However,** maybe you are trying to solve the wrong problem. There could be a better way to represent the concepts that you are currently trying to store as a regular expression. If you can devise a more specific "language" or structure for your matching, then theoretically, you can create an analyzer that can turn *that data* into field(s) that are indexable & optimizable.

**Example:** Maybe you just want to use regular expressions to match some ID code (like `1200ABC00012` or `1G021`) based on the number of numbers, then the number of letters, in its prefix. In that case, rather than indexing a regular expression, a better idea would be to index those two numbers instead: the number count and the letter count from the prefix. So if a search string is `DG56`, I might search for documents matching a query like `numberPrefixWidth:0 letterPrefixWidth:2`. Or for a search string `789FGH4`, my query would be `numberPrefixWidth:3 letterPrefixWidth:3`.

Because we have simplified the concepts actually represented in the document, there is no need to look at every document (and basically run a stored program) to find the one that matches. We can use Lucene to do the kind of search it's fast at.

**Note:** this answer also applies to your RDBMS example. If you are trying to do something in MariaDB like `WHERE someSearch REGEXP theRegexpColumn`, the engine has to run over every single row and evaluate it. There is no potential for index-based optimization whatsoever in a design like that. The difference is that Lucene is more special-purpose and doesn't have a language as broad as SQL to be able to easily run such a query without doing some of the work yourself.

Comment: First of all thank you for the elaborate answer! The REGEXP operator evaluation in the MariaDB is ultra quick, but still not as fast as Lucene (without the regex bit). For solving the above, I worked around it. I ended up running a Lucene query for all the other search criteria (but for the regex field), ensuring that I end up with a fistful of results (<10) and then evaluate the regex one-by-one in memory(Java). Of course there is a small penalty for doing so, but results look fine for the time being.